# use rails 4.0 strong parameter in non rails application

Tags: strong-parameters, grape-api

I use active-record 4.0 in a grape api application, but as strong parameter only works in rails controller, how do I permit params in a grape api class

Answer (score 8):

There seems to be a way to use the strong parameters outside the controller

```
raw_parameters = { :email => "john@example.com", :name => "John", :admin => true }
parameters = ActionController::Parameters.new(raw_parameters)
user = User.create(parameters.permit(:name, :email))
```

For more info check the repository documentation on github https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters

Regards

Comment: it is working for creating a new record but not working for update. Can you please help me in updating the record? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The same pattern should apply, only use `.update_attributes(parameters.permit(:name, :email)` instead of create.